# Project must list all files or use an 'include' pattern

Tags: typescript, tslint

I see this warning thrown in VSCode:

[image: VSCode Warning]

This is the line that throws the ts warning:

```js
import packageJson from "../package.json";
```

Weirdly, building and linting the project works fine:

```sh
$ tsc --project .
✨  Done in 1.16s.
```

```sh
$ tslint --config ../../tslint.json --project .
✨  Done in 1.59s.
```

Is this a warning caused by the VSCode parser, or is there something wrong in my `tsconfig.json` file?

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "files": [
    "package.json"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "outDir": "dist",
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "baseUrl": ".",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 91):

In my case I was builiding a monorepo and referencing one of the packages into another package.

All I had to do was remove `composite: true` from `tsconfig.json` and it worked.

Comment: It works! Why this is not accepted answer?
or maybe it raise another problem for others?

Comment: This worked for me, but what functionality are we losing by removing `composite`? I'm referring to my package `tsconfig.json` from a base `tsconfig.json` using `references`.

Comment: why does it work?!

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Setting `composite` to `false` disables enforcement of `includes` patterns [(see docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#composite). It's not clear to me why JSON files aren't included by default when writing wildcard globs, but specifically including `*.json` files seems to work fine (TS 5.2.2).

Answer (score 18):

As dumb as it sounds, restarting VSCode fixed this for me.

Comment: unbeliveable, but same for me :D

Comment: worked in my Jetbrains IDE (PyCharm) as well

Comment: same for me :)))

Comment: Same here. You don't have to re-start though. You can re-load the window: hit _F1_, serach for "reload developer window", select the entry and hit _Enter_. This solves a lot of issues with false errors in VSCode.

Answer (score 15):

Samuel's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70964056/1175942) works great for me.

I got the same error for another reason, I use `.json` files as static mocks for tests - importing them as modules. In my case the files are nested inside `src`, and adding an explicit pattern to include `.json` files did the trick for me.

Here's the relevant part in my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "include": [
    // ...other includes
    "src/**/*.json"
  ]
}
```

Referring to the question asked - this should work:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "package.json" // <---
  ]
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't very useful since you don't mention which file the above code is meant to go into.

Comment: @user275801 Obviously tsconfig

Comment: @idkwhatsgoingon Nothing ever is obvious

Answer (score 8):

Open your `tsconfig.node.json`, and add your files path in the includes just like `"include": ["vite.config.ts", "yourFilePath"],`

Comment: Adding `"src/folderName/*.json"` on tsconfig.include worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Add package.json to your includes. It out of src dir.

```
{ 
    "include": [
      "src/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ]
}
```

Comment: but I got: error TS6059: File 'package.json' is not under 'rootDir' 'src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Comment: Is your `rootDir` set to `src`? If so it won't work, remove `rootDir` or set to `"."`

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if your server is running when you add new files. If this is the case, simply stop it and start it again so that is can rebuild and include the new files.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

to your compiler options

Comment: I already had these in the topmost `tsconfig.json` file, but to make sure I also dropped it in the nested one (the file from the OP); it did NOT work

Comment: If this doesn’t work, you’re most likely running into this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/34676#issuecomment-557636399

Answer (score 2):

## On WebStorm

After including the file in `tsconfig.app.json`, I also had to do "File" > "Invalidate Caches and Restart" before the error went away.

EDIT: Sometimes it's enough to just restart the Vue Language Server (at the bottom right)

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure I would have ever figured this one out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

There's an incredibly long thread about this issue in the [TypeScript repository](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43838).

Although not a permanent fix, the easiest solution is restarting your TypeScript server.

`Ctrl + Shift + P` > `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`
With this, you don't have to restart vscode or reinstall `node_modules`.